# Thread safety in RDL with multiple datasets

Tags: concurrency, reporting-services

I have an RDL with multiple datasets, and the stored stored procedures which populate the datasets create and drop temp tables having the same name.

This report has been run 1000 times without any problem, but I wonder if there is a race condition waiting to happen. Its possible in principle for both stored procedures to be executed in parallel on the same connection, and both procedures attempt to create/drop the same temp tables with the same name -- I haven't tested this claim, I'm only speculating.

**Are multiples datasets in an RDL executed in parallel on the same connection?**

**If there is a concurrency issue in my report, how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are not `##<tablename>` which are global temp tables, you will be fine.   Regular temp tables `#<tablename>` are session specific.   Two different calls will each keep their own version of their `#<table>` in tempdb with names like `#table___________________________________________92343ABE452DC`